# Django; how to find all bugs that have certain flags set

Tags: python, django

I am writing a Django app that queries a Bugzilla database for reporting.  I am trying to build a query that can get all of the bugs that have specific flags set.

The model representing the flags table.

```
class Bugzilla_flags(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'flags'

    type_id = models.IntegerField()
    status = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    bug_id = models.IntegerField()
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField()
    modification_date = models.DateTimeField()
    setter_id = models.IntegerField()
    requestee_id = models.IntegerField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.bug_id)
```

I have a dictionary that represents the flags I want to look for (type_id : status).

```
flags = {'36':'?','12':'+'}
```

I tried using the reduce function but I don't think it will work because I is checking that all of the flags to be present in the same row.  If I run the query with a dictionary with just a single k,v pair, it works fine, but not with more than 1.

```
query = reduce(operator.and_, (Q(type_id=flag,status=val) for (flag,val) in flags.items()))
```

I will then take the results of that query, and use it as the search for the actual bugs database.

```
inner = Bugzilla_flags.objects.using('bugzilla').filter(query)
bugs = Bugzilla_bugs.objects.using('bugzilla').filter(bug_id__in=inner)
```

For some history, I am currently using a series of steps to generate some sql which I send as a raw query, but I am trying to see if I can do it in Django.  The resulting sql is like this:

```
select b.bug_id, b.priority, b.bug_severity, b.bug_status, b.resolution, b.cf_verified_in, b.assigned_to, b.qa_contact, b.short_desc, b.cf_customercase, 
   MAX(CASE WHEN f.type_id = 31 THEN f.status ELSE NULL END) as Unlocksbranch1, 
   MAX(CASE WHEN f.type_id = 31 THEN f.status ELSE NULL END) as Unlocksbranch2, 
   MAX(CASE WHEN f.type_id = 33 THEN f.status ELSE NULL END) as Unlocksbranch3, 
   MAX(CASE WHEN f.type_id = 34 THEN f.status ELSE NULL END) as Unlocksbranch4, 
   MAX(CA5E WHEN f.type_id = 36 THEN f.status ELSE NULL END) as Unlocksbranch5, 
   MAX(CASE WHEN f.type_id = 41 THEN f.status ELSE NULL END) as Unlocksbranch6, 
   MAX(CASE WHEN f.type_id = 12 THEN f.status ELSE NULL END) as CodeReviewed 
   from bugs b 
   inner join flags f on f.bug_id = b.bug_id 
   where ( b.bug_status = 'RESOLVED' or b.bug_status = 'VERIFIED' or b.bug_status = 'CLOSED' ) 
   and b.resolution = 'FIXED' 
   group by b.bug_id 
   having CodeReviewed = '+' and Unlocksbranch1 = '?' and Unlocksbranch2 = '+'
```

The result of this gives me a single queryset that has all of the flags I care about as columns, which I can then do my analysis on.  The last "having" section is what I am actually querying on, and is what I am trying to get with the above Django queries.

**EDIT**

Basically what I need to do is like this:

```
flags1 = {'36':'?'}
flags2 = {'12':'+'}

query1 = reduce(operator.and_, (Q(type_id=flag,status=val) for (flag,val) in flags1.items()))
query2 = reduce(operator.and_, (Q(type_id=flag,status=val) for (flag,val) in flags2.items()))

inner1 = Bugzilla_flags.objects.using('bugzilla').filter(query1)
inner2 = Bugzilla_flags.objects.using('bugzilla').filter(query2)

inner1_bugs = [row.bug_id for row in inner1]   # list of just the bug_ids
inner2_bugs = [row.bug_id for row in inner2]   # list of just the bug_ids

intersect = set(inner1_bugs) & set(inner2_bugs)
```

The intersect is a set that has all of the bug_ids that I can then use in the Bugzilla_bugs query to get the actual bug data.

How can I do the 3 operations (query, inner, inner_bugs) and then the intersect using a variable length dictionary input such as:

```
flags = {'36':'?','12':'+','15','?',etc}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `inner` query looks right to me. To find bugs that have all those flags, not just any one, you can either use `reduce` again to `and` together a bunch of `flag=` `Q` objects, or iterate and build up multiple filter clauses.

```
inner = Bugzilla_flags.objects.using('bugzilla').filter(query)
flag_filter = reduce(operator.and_, (Q(flag=flag) for flag in inner))
bugs = Bugzilla_bugs.objects.using('bugzilla').filter(flag_filter)
```

Or:

```
inner = Bugzilla_flags.objects.using('bugzilla').filter(query)
bugs = Bugzilla_bugs.objects.using('bugzilla').all()
for flag in inner:
    bugs = bugs.filter(flag=flag)
```

Or, for that matter, take advantage of the fact that multiple `Q` objects are `and`ed together:

```
inner = Bugzilla_flags.objects.using('bugzilla').filter(query)
flag_filters = [Q(flag=flag) for flag in inner]
bugs = Bugzilla_bugs.objects.using('bugzilla').filter(*flag_filters)
```

Comment: None of these work.  I always get zero rows when I do the Bugzilla_bugs query using the filter.  I did figure out how to get the intersect of the different filters, but I need a clean way to do it.  I edited the question.